# Is there any difference between initializing a NSDictionary using curly brackets or standard +dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I saw an Apple sample code with a NSDictionary being initialized using `@{ value:key }` notation. I use to initialize a constant NSDictionary using `+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`

My question is:

Is there any difference between the two generated NSDictionaries? Do I need to worry about memory leaking? I'm using ARC.

All I found about it is this Apple doc, but it is related to Mac, not iOS. And the notation is `@{ key = value }` and not `@{ value:key }`.

http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/LegacyTechnologies/WebObjects/WebObjects_3.1/DevGuide/WebScript/CreatingObjects.html

A second question would be: is that safe to use this to submit the app to App Store, or would it be considered "undocumented API"?

Thanks!

Comment: That link is for WebObjects, and does not apply to normal objective-c, which is why the syntax is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I use… `+dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` … Is there any difference between the two generated NSDictionaries?

The compiler uses `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]`. So the 'gotcha' is that the parameters/values you use in these literal expression must not be `nil`. When you use `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`, the input stops when nil is encountered. It is an error to pass `nil` to a literal expression as a key or value to a literal expression. This may change your program (because semantics of dictionary creation through va_lists are different), but the stricter semantics would likely result in detecting bugs, more than anything.

> Do I need to worry about memory leaking? I'm using ARC.

You might need an autorelease pool in some cases -- that depends on the context you create it in.

> Is that safe to use this to submit the app to App Store, or would it be considered "undocumented API"?

You will need Apple-Clang 4.0 (Xcode 4.4). It is compatible with all versions of OS X and iOS:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html

More details here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: They did practically a whole session on it at WWDC ("Modern Objective-C"), and tons of their sample code and docs uses literals. It's all documented at the llvm site. I'd be shocked if they considered that "undocumented".

Comment: @CarlVeazey yes - this is probably what you are referring to: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html. there is a specific reference i want to use for the last question, but i have to find it first :)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I didn't know the correct name to look it for... It will save a lot of time when coding. :)